# Antlr4 star ('*') operator consuming large amount of memory

Tags: c#, antlr, antlr4

I am working to rework parts of my grammar to reduce its memory consumption.  I am stuck on a rule that contains the star ('*') operator.  I have tried a couple of different things but every time I run the generated c# code it quickly eats up over 2GB of memory when attempts to match the contents of the starred rule but fails to find a match.  I believe I am using the star operator correctly for cases that will occur 0 or more times.  Any help would be appreciated.  This this rule below:

```
hierarchical_identifier_branch_index_star : (hierarchical_identifier_branch_index)* ;
hierarchical_identifier_branch_index : Left_bracket hierarchical_identifier_branch_index_expr Right_bracket ;
hierarchical_identifier_branch_index_expr : expression | Dollar ;
```

Comment: Try making hierarchical_identifier_branch_index_star : (hierarchical_identifier_branch_index)* a plus loop instead and make hierarchical_identifier_branch_index_star optional in the calling rule.

Comment: This seemed to help some.  It avoid the problem on the "0" case.  Still seeing a lot of memory consumption on the "1+" case.  Working on optimizing other parts of the grammar and it appears to helping this too.  Not sure why.  The other parts of the grammar I am working on now are not related to these rules.